# Split a string into two, space separated

Tags: string, bash, awk

I have a string `000012340012` and need to separate it into two.

The separation should be made before the last four digits, both strings must have a spacing of 10 blanks: `00001234          0012`.

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `awk` may help here too.

```
echo "000012340012" | awk '{print substr($0,1,length($0)-3) "          " substr($0,length($0)-3)}'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

num=000012340012
echo "${num:0:-4}          ${num: -4}"
```

Using bash parameter expansion as covered in the [Shell Parameter Expansion section](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) of [the Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html).

Answer (score 3):

This sed one-liner does it:

```
 sed  's/....$/          &/'
```

with your example:

```
kent$ sed  's/....$/          &/' <<<"000012340012"  
00001234          0012
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure Bash (`printf` and parameter substring expansion are shell builtins):

```sh
x=000012340012
printf "%10s%10s\n" ${x:0:-4} ${x: -4}
```